# Decreasing iteration time through better vectorization

Tags: r, performance, vectorization, lapply, do.call

I'm trying to substantially decrease computing time for my code.

I have 2 data.frames:

1.NewCus_withGeo

```
head(newCus)
      U_ID    U_LAT    U_LONG
  31902101 47.57080 -52.69588
  26428781 45.50141 -73.55854
  26428801 45.40768 -73.95121
  28130841 45.44952 -73.82955
  26428961 45.54130 -73.47751
  26428981 45.35496 -75.67068
```

2.localD

```
head(localD)
           ID    D_ID    D_LAT    D_LONG
1533582_23821 1533582 45.40462 -75.62618
1533582_97592 1533582 45.21759 -75.71293
1533582_23811 1533582 46.83400 -71.28574
4126692_23811 4126692 46.79560 -71.27572
4134402_23811 4134402 46.74568 -71.44606
4135162_23811 4135162 46.82987 -71.23739
4138752_23841 4138752 46.34229 -72.54294
```

I want to get for every `U_ID` the 5 `D_ID` with smallest euclidean distance but only if that distance is under 0.3.

I want as a result another data.frame containing for each `U_ID` with close enough `D_ID` the 5 closest `D_ID` and the distance between `U_ID` and `D_ID` which would look like this:

```
head(result_df)
         U_ID    D_ID         dist
     26428781 4244252 0.0008656102
     26428781 4088692 0.0055139426
     26428781 4177752 0.0060150366
     26428781 4182572 0.0067220964
     26428781 4191862 0.0076759495
     26428801 4135212 0.0455715423
     26428801 4216202 0.0726350403
```

I came up with this code to do it:

### EDIT Thanks to Rui Barradas who improved function's performance

### EDIT 2 to further improve function's performance we can use data.table to improve time on subseting

```
library(data.table)
newCus = data.table(newCus)

distance <- function(x,y){
 # Subsetting newCus to get only one U_ID
 tb <- newCus[U_ID == x]

 # distance calculations
 dist = (tb$U_LAT - y$D_LAT)^2 + (tb$U_LONG - y$D_LONG)^2

 if(min(dist) <= 0.3^2){

   # Putting the data.frame together
   NewCus_dist <- data.frame(U_ID = tb$U_ID, D_ID = y$D_ID, dist = dist)
   # Keeping top 5 D_ID
   NewCus_dist <- NewCus_dist[order(dist)[1:5], ]
   NewCus_dist$dist <- sqrt(NewCus_dist$dist)

 } else {
   NewCus_dist <- NULL
 }
 NewCus_dist
}
```

Then using this function in a do.call and lapply function to iterate over the `U_ID` and get the result in a data.frame

```
 result_df = do.call("rbind", lapply(newCus$U_ID, distance, localD))
```

Is there a better and faster way to code this?

Comment: which distance measure are you calculating? euclidean?

Comment: Yes euclidean measure between (U_LAT, U_LONG) and (D_LAT, D_LONG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(Rcpp)
require(data.table)

cppFunction(
  "List m(std::vector<std::string> & names, NumericMatrix & x,
  std::vector<std::string> & names2, NumericMatrix & y){

    unsigned int nx = x.nrow();
    unsigned int ny = y.nrow();
    std::vector<std::string> c1;
    std::vector<std::string> c2;
    NumericVector c3;
    double d; double d1; double d2;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<nx; ++i) {
      int sk = 0;
      for (unsigned int j=0; j<ny; ++j)  {
        d1 = x(i, 0) - y(j, 0);
        d2 = x(i, 1) - y(j, 1);
        d = sqrt(d1*d1 + d2*d2);

        if ((d < 0.3) & (sk < 5)) {
          c1.push_back(names[i]);
          c2.push_back(names2[j]);
          c3.push_back(d);
          ++sk;
        }
      }
    }
    return List::create( 
      _[\"U_ID\"]  = c1, 
      _[\"D_ID\"]  = c2, 
      _[\"dist\"] = c3);
  }")

cpp <- function(x, y) { # function which prepears data and executes Cpp function
  n1 <- as.character(x[[1]])
  c1 <- as.matrix(x[,-1])
  n2 <- as.character(y[[2]])
  c2 <- as.matrix(y[, -(1:2)])
  r <- m(n1, c1, n2, c2)
  as.data.table(r)
}

cpp(newCus, localD)
# U_ID    D_ID       dist
# 1: 26428981 1533582 0.06668107
# 2: 26428981 1533582 0.14372049

# Prevous function:
r <- function(x, y) do.call("rbind", lapply(x$U_ID, distance2, y))
r(newCus, localD)
# U_ID    D_ID       dist
# 1 26428981 1533582 0.06668107
# 2 26428981 1533582 0.14372049
# 7 26428981 4138752 3.27987470
# 5 26428981 4134402 4.44764165
# 4 26428981 4126692 4.62505319
```

I think that distance is not calculated correctly in distance2 function, there should be also `sqrt`. Or am I wrong?

### Benchmaks

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(r(newCus, localD),
          cpp(newCus, localD),
          replications = 1000,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"))
# test replications elapsed relative
# 2 cpp(newCus, localD)         1000    0.91    1.000
# 1   r(newCus, localD)         1000    2.35    2.582

# with bigger data:
benchmark(r(newCus2, localD2),
          cpp(newCus2, localD2),
          replications = 3,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"))
# test replications elapsed relative
# 2 cpp(newCus2, localD2)            3    0.86    1.000
# 1   r(newCus2, localD2)            3    9.11   10.593
```

About 10 times faster than previous solution.

### Update

Corrected function:

```
cppFunction(
  "List m(std::vector<std::string> & names, NumericMatrix & x,
  std::vector<std::string> & names2, NumericMatrix & y){

    unsigned int nx = x.nrow();
    unsigned int ny = y.nrow();
    std::vector<std::string> c1;
    std::vector<std::string> c2;
    NumericVector c3;
    double d; double d1; double d2;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<nx; ++i) {
      for (unsigned int j=0; j<ny; ++j)  {
        d1 = x(i, 0) - y(j, 0);
        d2 = x(i, 1) - y(j, 1);
        d = sqrt(d1*d1 + d2*d2);

        if ((d < 0.3)) {
          c1.push_back(names[i]);
          c2.push_back(names2[j]);
          c3.push_back(d);
        }
      }
    }
    return List::create( 
      _[\"U_ID\"]  = c1, 
      _[\"D_ID\"]  = c2, 
      _[\"dist\"] = c3);
  }")

cpp <- function(x, y) { # function which prepears data and executes Cpp function
  n1 <- as.character(x[[1]])
  c1 <- as.matrix(x[,-1])
  n2 <- as.character(y[[2]])
  c2 <- as.matrix(y[, -(1:2)])
  r <- m(n1, c1, n2, c2)
  r <- as.data.table(r)
  setkey(r, U_ID, dist)
  r[, head(.SD, 5), U_ID][]
  }
```

Now you should get your desired results.

Comment: the sqrt is only calculated if the distance meets the minimum threshold.

Comment: No I meant distance2 function calculate the sqrt only when the distance meets the minimum threshold
Thank you for your answer minem.

Comment: @P_Sta then my answer helped you? if so, you should accept mine answer. Or if not, then Ruis' answer, if he answered your question..

Comment: I feel like the function doesn't take the 5 shortest distances, but take the first 5 distances. How could I keep only the 5 shortest distances?

Comment: @P_Sta Yes, I forgot about that, see update in my answer and try the updated function `cpp`. Now the results should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code that follows is not vectorized, but there's already a significant speed gain.

Now, this is basically your function, with some improvements, mostly to get rid of useless stuff.

```
distance2 <- function(x,y){
   # Subsetting newCus to get only one U_ID
   tb <- newCus[newCus$U_ID == x, ]

   # distance calculations
   dist = (tb$U_LAT - y$D_LAT)^2 + (tb$U_LONG - y$D_LONG)^2

   if(min(dist) <= 0.3^2){

       # Putting the data.frame together
       NewCus_dist <- data.frame(U_ID = tb$U_ID, D_ID = y$D_ID, dist = dist)
       # Keeping top 5 D_ID
       NewCus_dist <- NewCus_dist[order(dist)[1:5], ]
       NewCus_dist$dist <- sqrt(NewCus_dist$dist)

   } else {
       NewCus_dist <- NULL
   }
   NewCus_dist
}

res1 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(newCus$U_ID, distance, localD))
res2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(newCus$U_ID, distance2, localD))
all.equal(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
```

Now the timing of both `distance` and `distance2`. For this I've made up bigger input data frames.

```
newCus2 <- newCus
localD2 <- localD
for(i in 1:1e2){
    newCus2 <- rbind(newCus2, newCus)
    localD2 <- rbind(localD2, localD)
}

system.time({
res1 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(newCus2$U_ID, distance, localD2))
})
   user  system elapsed 
    1.7     0.0     1.7
system.time({
res2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(newCus2$U_ID, distance2, localD2))
})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.00    0.17
```

A speed gain of a ten fold, an order of magnitude. So far that's it. Maybe someone will find a better, vectorized solution.

Comment: I am not an "r" programmer, but generally the data needs to be contiguous to be vectorizable. This means that rather than an array of structures, a structure of arrays then allows all the lats and lons to be contiguous. Once you have the delta-Lat, then it may be possible to "Thin the herd" on the delta-longitude values to compute, before RSS'íng then together.